# Change Route Based S2S to Policy Based

Tags: vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn

I have a route-based S2S VPN setup on Azure but discovered the on-premise only supports static routing. Is it possible to convert the route based to policy based? 
The reason I want this is to preserve the public IP which is dynamically assigned on Azure.

Is there a limit on number of policy based VPN on a VNET since I can't do multi-site connections on policy based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert the route based to policy based?

No,you could not covert route-based gateway to policy-based gateway. **Once a virtual network gateway has been created, you can't change the VPN type. You have to delete the virtual network gateway and create a new one.**

More information about VPN gateway please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-gateway-settings#a-namevpntypeavpn-types).